# Disable button if input value is zero only by regexp

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to enable submit button only after integer value inserted . But if user input 0 only , dont enable submit button . However zero leading integer is ok .

Example

- input value = 0  ----> disable submit
- input value = 01 ----> enable submit
- input value = 10 ----> enable submit
- input value = aa ----> disable sumbit

```js
$("#numberInput").on("keyup", function() {
  const regexp_ = new RegExp("^[1-9][0-9]+$");
  
  if (regexp_.test(this.value)) {
    $("#form_submit_btn").removeClass("invalid-btn").prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
   $("#form_submit_btn").addClass("invalid-btn").prop("disabled", true);
   }
});
```

```css
.input {
display: block;
outline: none;
border: none;
box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.23);
padding: 5px;
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}



.btn {
 outline: none;
 border: 0;
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px blue;
 background: blue;
 border-radius: 0;
 padding: 5px 20px;
 color: white;
 }

form {
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.23);
 padding: 15px 30px;
}

.invalid-btn {
background: none;
box-shadow: none;
color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="input" id="numberInput">
  <input type="submit" class="btn invalid-btn" id="form_submit_btn" disabled>
 </form>
```

> I think I can solve by adding that input value is greater than zero . But I want to solve only by regexp expression . So advice me..

Comment: @PoulBak - That will fail to match `01` (or even just `1`), which is wanted. Also unnecessarily complex `[0]*?` where a plain `0*` would suffice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$`

This accepts any number of digits, as long as at least one of them is non-zero.

As a side-note, during testing, make sure that the input `010` gives the expected behaviour; the backend may treat it as either 10 or 8, at least one of which could be surprising to the users.

Comment: This is the best one . Can you explain me a bit about `*` . What is exactly do in expression ?

Comment: The `*` means "zero or more of the preceding element", so `[0-9]*` means "zero or more digits", `.*` means "any amount of anything" and so on. If you want a full mathematical definition, look up "[Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star)".

Comment: By the way, looking at the other answers, an even simpler expression would be `^0*[1-9][0-9]*$`

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp currently reports both `01` and `1` as invalid inputs; the following modification will make it work on these cases as well: `^0*[1-9]\d*$`.
`\d` is an alias for `[0-9]` and `*` lets the input have zero or more of that element.

You could simplify this regular expression by splitting it into two expressions: `[1-9]` (look for a non-zero digit) and `^\d+$` (check that the input is only numerical).
Your code would become:

```js
$("#numberInput").on("keyup", function() {
  const regexp_1 = new RegExp("[1-9]");
  const regexp_2 = new RegExp("^\d+$");
  
  if (regexp_1.test(this.value) && regexp_2.test(this.value)) {
    $("#form_submit_btn").removeClass("invalid-btn").prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $("#form_submit_btn").addClass("invalid-btn").prop("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this `^[1-9]$|^[0-9][1-9]+$|^[1-9][0-9]+$`

```js
$("#numberInput").on("keyup", function() {
  const regexp_ = new RegExp(^[1-9]$|^[0-9][1-9]+$|^[1-9][0-9]+$");
  
  if (regexp_.test(this.value)) {
    $("#form_submit_btn").removeClass("invalid-btn").prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
   $("#form_submit_btn").addClass("invalid-btn").prop("disabled", true);
   }
});
```

```css
.input {
display: block;
outline: none;
border: none;
box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.23);
padding: 5px;
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}



.btn {
 outline: none;
 border: 0;
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px blue;
 background: blue;
 border-radius: 0;
 padding: 5px 20px;
 color: white;
 }

form {
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.23);
 padding: 15px 30px;
}

.invalid-btn {
background: none;
box-shadow: none;
color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="input" id="numberInput">
  <input type="submit" class="btn invalid-btn" id="form_submit_btn" disabled>
 </form>
```

Comment: This will accept the input `00` which is probably not wanted?

Comment: @sabik need to OP to clarify it

Comment: @sabik Thank you for your answer . zero is not wanted .

Comment: @DavidJawHpan Updated my answer,you can check it now

Answer (score 0):

My regexp here:

```js
const integerPattern = "^(\d(?=\d)|[1-9])+\d*$";
```

I've checked it for these cases:

```
01 // true
0 // false
2 // true
10 // true
3 // true
1000 // true
1231 // true
14145 // true
-10 // false
```

Comment: This (a) seems overly complicated, with the lookahead; and (b) matches `00` which is probably not wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
^([0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*([0-9]+)?)$
```

Example
https://regexr.com/5ctln

Comment: The `([0-9]+)?` part seems superfluous, since it's duplicate with and a synonym for the already-present `[0-9]*` part?